ImageNet 2012 - loading images as array
I've written code to load segments of ImageNet 2012 and return it as an np.array and while the code works for most cases some images are problematic for the code as they aren't in the RGB format.
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import argparse

def load_image_list (PATH, IMAGE_LIST):
    output_list = []
    for fname in IMAGE_LIST:
        img_pil = Image.open(PATH + '/' + fname)
        if img_pil.mode == 'CMYK':
            img_pil = img_pil.convert('RGB')
        width, height = img_pil.size
        smallest_dim = min((width, height))
        left = (width - smallest_dim)/2
        right = (width + smallest_dim)/2
        top = (height - smallest_dim)/2
        bottom = (height + smallest_dim)/2
        img_pil = img_pil.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
        img_pil = img_pil.resize((224,224))
        img_pil.load()

    img1 = np.asarray(img_pil, dtype="float32")
    if img1.ndim == 2:
        img1 = np.stack((img1,)*3, axis=-1)
    
    img1 = np.rollaxis(np.array(img1),2,0).astype(np.float32)
    output_list.append(img1)
try:
    output_list = np.array(output_list, dtype="float32")
except:
    counter = 0
    helper = -1
    for o in output_list:
        print(counter, o.shape)
        counter += 1
        if(o.shape[0] == 4):
            print(o)
            helper = output_list.index(o)
    counter = 0
    for name in IMAGE_LIST:
        print(counter, name)
        counter += 1


    print(helper, IMAGE_LIST[helper])
    print(helper, output_list[helper].shape)
    retry_item = IMAGE_LIST[helper]
    img_pil = Image.open(PATH + '/' + retry_item)
    width, height = img_pil.size
    smallest_dim = min((width, height))
    left = (width - smallest_dim)/2
    right = (width + smallest_dim)/2
    top = (height - smallest_dim)/2
    bottom = (height + smallest_dim)/2
    img_pil = img_pil.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    img_pil = img_pil.resize((224,224))
    img_pil.load()

    img1 = np.asarray(img_pil, dtype="float32")
    print('number of dimensions: ', img1.ndim)
    print('shape: ', img1.shape)
    if img1.ndim == 2:
        print('ndim was 2')
        print(img1)
        img1 = np.stack((img1,)*3, axis=-1)
    img1 = np.rollaxis(np.array(img1),2,0).astype(np.float32)
    print('number of dimensions: ', img1.ndim)
    print('shape: ', img1.shape)
    
output_list = np.array(output_list, dtype="float32")  


output_list = output_list/255        
return output_list

The except line is to find out whenit breaks why it does. I can already load every image in the valdiation set but now I've tried running on the test set and I got an error again with the image  n02105855_2933.JPEG, because the loaded Image is 4-dimensional instead of 3-dimensional. Is there a better way to load an JPEG of unknown color format as an RGB image? And what other color formats are used in ImageNet 2012?

The problem with the specific image was that it was in the rgba format with the a dimension being all 255's. So the following code solves that problem:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import argparse


def load_image_list (PATH, IMAGE_LIST):
output_list = []
for fname in IMAGE_LIST:
    img_pil = Image.open(PATH + '/' + fname)
    if img_pil.mode == 'CMYK':
        img_pil = img_pil.convert('RGB')
    width, height = img_pil.size
    smallest_dim = min((width, height))
    left = (width - smallest_dim)/2
    right = (width + smallest_dim)/2
    top = (height - smallest_dim)/2
    bottom = (height + smallest_dim)/2
    img_pil = img_pil.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    img_pil = img_pil.resize((224,224))
    img_pil.load()

    img1 = np.asarray(img_pil, dtype="float32")
    if img1.ndim == 2:
        img1 = np.stack((img1,)*3, axis=-1)
    if img1.shape[2] == 4:
        img1 = np.delete(img1, 3, axis=2)
    
    img1 = np.rollaxis(np.array(img1),2,0).astype(np.float32)
    output_list.append(img1)
try:
    output_list = np.array(output_list, dtype="float32")
except:
    counter = 0
    helper = -1
    for o in output_list:
        print(counter, o.shape)
        counter += 1
        if(o.shape[0] == 4):
            print(o)
            helper = output_list.index(o)
    counter = 0
    for name in IMAGE_LIST:
        print(counter, name)
        counter += 1


    print(helper, IMAGE_LIST[helper])
    print(helper, output_list[helper].shape)
    retry_item = IMAGE_LIST[helper]
    img_pil = Image.open(PATH + '/' + retry_item)
    width, height = img_pil.size
    smallest_dim = min((width, height))
    left = (width - smallest_dim)/2
    right = (width + smallest_dim)/2
    top = (height - smallest_dim)/2
    bottom = (height + smallest_dim)/2
    img_pil = img_pil.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    img_pil = img_pil.resize((224,224))
    img_pil.load()

    img1 = np.asarray(img_pil, dtype="float32")
    print('number of dimensions: ', img1.ndim)
    print('shape: ', img1.shape)
    if img1.ndim == 2:
        print('ndim was 2')
        print(img1)
        img1 = np.stack((img1,)*3, axis=-1)
    if img1.shape[2] == 4:
        print('color dimension was size 4')
        img1 = np.delete(img1, 3, axis=2)
    
    img1 = np.rollaxis(np.array(img1),2,0).astype(np.float32)
    print('number of dimensions: ', img1.ndim)
    print('shape: ', img1.shape)
    
    output_list = np.array(output_list, dtype="float32")  


output_list = output_list/255        
return output_list
    

